# How do you determine the object of a verb in a rather long sentence like this?

Tags: verbs, objects

> Eric Leed identiﬁes and provides historical, sociological and
> psychological insights about the different elements that together
> combine to form a journey, carried out by a traveller.

In the above sentence, which is the object of the verb "identify"? Is it "insights" or "elements" and why? If you only consider grammar rather than meaning, are they both legitimate candidates for the object?

Comment: The Od of the coordination "identifies and provides" is the whole "historical, sociological and psychological insights about the different elements that together combine to form a journey, carried out by a traveller". The Od is one long noun phrase with "insights" as head.

Comment: I don't recognise the abbreviation "Od", @BillJ

Answer (score 3):

There's no 'one-size-fits-all' approach to determining what you are asking, but here's a simple approach.

You know that the most basic sentence is *subject-verb-object*, right? For example, "I like apples", or "the dog ate the biscuit". Once you strip away information that is parenthetical, defining clauses etc, you'll be left with something resembling a basic sentence.

- Eric Leed **(subject)**
- identiﬁes and provides **(verbs)**
- historical, sociological and psychological insights **(object)**
- about the different elements that together combine to form a journey, carried out by a traveller **(additional information about the object)**

So, put simply, *Eric provides insights*.

Answer (score 1):

> *Eric Leed identiﬁes and provides* [*historical, sociological and*
> *psychological insights about the different elements that together*
> *combine to form a journey, carried out by a traveller*].

The object of the coordination of transitive verbs "identifies" and "provides" is the whole of the NP (noun phrase) "historical, sociological and psychological insights about the different elements that together combine to form a journey, carried out by a traveller". Note that like most objects it is located immediately after the verb.

The NP object has the noun "insights" as head, with the *about* preposition phrase as its complement. The NP "the different elements that together combine to form a journey, carried out by a traveller" is object of the preposition "about", not object of the verbs.